# jQuery Validation in a Modal to send data via php

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation, modal-dialog

I have a problem that its making me crazy. I have modal with a form that is validating with jquery validation plugin, this works! but is not sending the data to php to be store in the database.

I read a lot but nothing can solve my problem.

**This is the JS:**

```
$( "#add_cliente" ).validate( {

rules: {
  nomb1_clie: {
    required: true,
    lettersonly: true,
    minlength: 2
  },
  nomb2_clie: {
    lettersonly: true,
    minlength: 2
  },
  apel1_clie: {
    required: true,
    lettersonly: true,
    minlength: 2
  },
  apel2_clie: {
    lettersonly: true,
    minlength: 2
  },
  usuar_clie: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
  },
  contr_clie: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 5
  },
  confirm_password: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    equalTo: "#contr_clie"
  },
  telef_clie: {
    required: true,
    number: false,
    minlength: 15
  },
  email_clie: {
    required: true,
    email: true
  },
},

messages: {
  nomb1_clie: {
    required: "Ingrese su Primer Nombre",
    lettersonly: "Tu Nombre solo debe contener letras sin espacios",
    minlength: "Tu Nombre debe contener al menos 2 caracteres"
  },
  nomb2_clie: {
    lettersonly: "Tu Nombre solo debe contener letras sin espacios",
    minlength: "Tu Nombre debe contener al menos 2 caracteres"
  },
  apel1_clie: {
    required: "Ingrese su Primer Apellido",
    lettersonly: "Tu Apellido solo debe contener letras sin espacios",
    minlength: "Tu Apellido debe contener al menos 2 caracteres"
  },
  apel2_clie: {
    lettersonly: "Tu Apellido solo debe contener letras sin espacio",
    minlength: "Tu Apellido debe contener al menos 2 caracteres"
  },
  usuar_clie: {
    required: "Ingrese un Nombre de Usuario",
    minlength: "Tu Nombre de Usuario debe contener al menos 2 caracteres"
  },
  contr_clie: {
    required: "Ingrese una Contraseña",
    minlength: "Tu Contraseña debe contener al menos 5 caracteres"
  },
  confirm_password: {
    required: "Ingrese una Contraseña",
    minlength: "Tu Contraseña debe contener al menos 5 caracteres",
    equalTo: "Ingrese la Misma Contraseña"
  },
  telef_clie: {
    required: "Ingrese un Número de Teléfono Valido",
    number: "Ingrese un Número de Teléfono Valido",
    minlength: "Ingrese un Número de Teléfono Valido"
  },
  email_clie: "Ingrese una Dirección de Correo Electrónico Válida"
},

errorElement: "em",
errorPlacement: function ( error, element ) {
  // Add the `invalid-feedback` class to the error element
  error.addClass( "invalid-feedback" );

  if ( element.prop( "type" ) === "checkbox" ) {
    error.insertAfter( element.next( "label" ) );
  } else {
    error.insertAfter( element );
  }
},
highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
  $( element ).addClass( "is-invalid" ).removeClass( "is-valid" );
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $( element ).addClass( "is-valid" ).removeClass( "is-invalid" );
},

submitHandler: function( form ) {

  var parametros = $(this).serialize();
  $('form :input').val('');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../ajax/guardar_cliente.php",
    data: parametros,
     beforeSend: function(objeto){
      $("#resultados").html("Enviando...");
      },
    success: function(datos){
    $("#resultados").html(datos);
    load(1);
    $('#addClienteModal').modal('hide');
    }                     
  });
}
```

});

I read about the submithandler but also not working.

**The way that is working to sending the data is this way**, but in this way its not validating nothing:

```
$( "#add_cliente" ).submit(function( event ) {


var parametros = $(this).serialize();
  $('form :input').val('');
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../ajax/guardar_cliente.php",
      data: parametros,
       beforeSend: function(objeto){
        $("#resultados").html("Enviando...");
        },
      success: function(datos){
      $("#resultados").html(datos);
      load(1);
      $('#addClienteModal').modal('hide');
      }
  });

  event.preventDefault();

});
```

This way without the validation works! but its not what i am looking for.

**And here is the HTML:**

```
<div id="addClienteModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form name="add_cliente" id="add_cliente" class="justify-content-center" align="center" action="">
            <div class="modal-header">                      
                <h4 class="modal-title">Registrar Cliente</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">                    
                <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="nomb1_clie">Primer Nombre: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomb1_clie" autocomplete="off" id="nomb1_clie" placeholder="Carlos" maxlength="20" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="nomb2_clie">Segundo Nombre: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomb2_clie" autocomplete="off" id="nomb2_clie" placeholder="Agustin" maxlength="20" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="apel1_clie">Primer Apellido: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apel1_clie" autocomplete="off" id="apel1_clie" placeholder="Guanipa" maxlength="20" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="apel2_clie">Segundo Apellido: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apel2_clie" autocomplete="off" id="apel2_clie" placeholder="Alvarez" maxlength="20" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="gener_clie">Genero: </label>
        <select class="form-control" id="gener_clie" name="gener_clie">
          <option value="MASCULINO">MASCULINO</option>
          <option value="FEMENINO">FEMENINO</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="telef_clie">Telefono: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control telef-mask" name="telef_clie" autocomplete="off" id="telef_clie" placeholder="(0000) 000 0000" maxlength="15">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="email_clie">E-Mail: </label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email_clie" autocomplete="off" id="email_clie" placeholder="correo@mail.com" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="usuar_clie">Usuario: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuar_clie" autocomplete="off" id="usuar_clie" placeholder="miusuario" maxlength="20" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="contr_clie">Contraseña: </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="contr_clie" autocomplete="off" id="contr_clie" placeholder="********" maxlength="20">
      </div>
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="confirm_password">Confirmar Contraseña: </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" autocomplete="off" id="confirm_password" placeholder="********" maxlength="20">
      </div>
    </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Registrar">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And the PHP to save the data**

```
<?php

require_once ("../paginas/conexion_bd.php"); //Contiene Funcion que Conecta a la Base de Datos



// escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
  $nomb1_clie = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["nomb1_clie"],ENT_QUOTES)));
  $nomb2_clie = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["nomb2_clie"],ENT_QUOTES)));
  $apel1_clie = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["apel1_clie"],ENT_QUOTES)));
  $apel2_clie = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["apel2_clie"],ENT_QUOTES)));
  $gener_clie = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["gener_clie"],ENT_QUOTES)));
  $telef_clie = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["telef_clie"],ENT_QUOTES)));
  $email_clie = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["email_clie"],ENT_QUOTES)));
  $usuar_clie = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["usuar_clie"],ENT_QUOTES)));
  $contr_clie = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["contr_clie"],ENT_QUOTES)));
  $fecre_clie = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp = time());
    $statu_clie = 1;

    // Registrar en la Base de Datos
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabma_clie(nomb1_clie, nomb2_clie, apel1_clie, apel2_clie, gener_clie, telef_clie, email_clie, usuar_clie, contr_clie, fecre_clie, statu_clie) VALUES ('$nomb1_clie','$nomb2_clie','$apel1_clie','$apel2_clie','$gener_clie','$telef_clie','$email_clie','$usuar_clie','$contr_clie','$fecre_clie','$statu_clie')";

    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    // Si ha sido Agregado Exitosamentee
    if ($query) {
        $messages[] = "El cliente ha sido registrado con éxito.";
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Lo sentimos, el registro falló. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo.";
    }


if (isset($errors)){        
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong>Error!</strong> 
            <?php
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                        echo $error;
                    }
                ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    if (isset($messages)){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
                <?php
                    foreach ($messages as $message) {
                            echo $message;
                        }
                    ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

I try to figure it out readind and searching but cannot see the mistake or the way to do it right. Hope anyone out there can help me! Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your submitHandler

```
submitHandler: function( form ) {

  var parametros = $( form ).serialize(); // I change 'this' to form
  console.log(parametros); // for test purpose. See your log to confirm the result data
  $('form :input').val('');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../ajax/guardar_cliente.php",
    data: parametros,
     beforeSend: function(objeto){
      $("#resultados").html("Enviando...");
      },
    success: function(datos){
    $("#resultados").html(datos);
    load(1);
    $('#addClienteModal').modal('hide');
    }                     
  });
}
```

Comment: That was all the problem.... Thank You! I am very grateful! Now continue working!